# Discord await messages timing out | Discord V12

Tags: discord.js

I am stuck on a problem. When "Player 2" (player[1]) types !yes in the channel then  reason it times out. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  player[1] is defined as `msg.mentions.members.first();`

```js
       let answer = true;
        
    
        if (players[1].user.bot) {
        return;
        } else {
                   
            answer = await msg.channel.awaitMessages((msg) => {
                console.log(msg.author.id === players[1].id && msg.content === `!yes`)  // returns true
                if (msg.author.id === players[1].id && msg.content === `!yes`) {
                    console.log("Player has accepted") // The console does print "Player has accepted"
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }, {maxMatches: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time']})
            .catch(() => {
                console.log("Timed out!") // The console does print "Timed Out as well"
                return false;
            });
        }

        // if user refuses to play
        if (!answer) {
            return channel.send(`${players[1]} preferred to run away.`);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax for `awaitMessages()` - the first argument should be a `CollectorFilter` (see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorFilter)), not a callback.

Consider using `createMessageCollector()` instead. It reads much more nicely than `awaitMessages()` and makes more sense than forcing async/await into a collector.  Should look something like this:

```js
const filter = m => (m.author.id===players[1].id && m.content==="!yes");
const collector = msg.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {max: 1, time: 30000});

collector.on("collect", (m) => {
  // Player has accepted... do whatever
});
collector.on("end", (reason) => {
  if(reason === "time") {
     // Ran out of time
  }
});
```